# Populating a datagridview with a defined class?

Tags: c#, class, datagridview, datagrid

So I'm having trouble getting a `datagrid` to populate with a class I have created. The class looks like so:

```
public class Shell
{
    public string shellURL { get; set; }
    public string shellStatus { get; set; }

    public Shell(string shellURL, string shellStatus)
    {
        this.shellURL = shellURL;
        this.shellStatus = shellStatus;
    }
}
```

I tried to do the following method but it's not populating correctly, it's just adding `Shell.shelllist` or something like that not the actual strings. I want the `datagrid` to populate with the shell url and shell status.

```
var source = new BindingSource();
rawShellsDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
source.DataSource = shellList.Select(x => new { Shell = x }).ToList();
rawShellsDataGrid.DataSource = source;
```

How would I go about populating the `datagrid` with the actual variables of the `shelllist` list? I find `datagrid`s very tricky, ideally I'd like to predefine the columns but I had absolutely no success with that, just empty columns were added.

I want the `datagrid` to auto generate the columns of the `Shell` class and add their values.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always build a DataTable which is easy to bind

```
    public class Shell
    {
        public string shellURL { get; set; }
        public string shellStatus { get; set; }

        public Shell(string shellURL, string shellStatus)
        {
            this.shellURL = shellURL;
            this.shellStatus = shellStatus;
        }
        public DataTable BuildTable(List<Shell> shells)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("URL", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));

            foreach(Shell shell in shells)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { shell.shellURL, shell.shellStatus});
            }

            return dt;
        }|
    }
```

Comment: Seems like exactly what I want but can you explain it to me please? For example how do you bind the datatable to the actual data grid, also how this functions overall. I need to understand :)

Comment: Nevermind after research I figured it out myself, thank you sir!